# Does onload_tcpdump support PGM option?

Tags: onload, tcpdump, onload-event, openonload

I want to dump PGM data through onload_tcpdump

Can we enable PGM option in onload_tcpdump to fetch PGM data?

Answer (score 0):

Onload supports the acceleration of TCP, UDP and Linux pipes. It therefore doesn't accelerate PGM (different IP protocol number) so any traffic using this would pass through the kernel and not the Onload stack. Due to this it would appear in `tcpdump` and not `onload_tcpdump`.